# Is $g(X|Y=y)$ equivalent to $g(X)|Y=y$?

Tags: probability, notation, random-variables, conditional-probability, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with marginal pdfs $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, respectively, and joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Then for all $y$ such that $f_Y(y) \neq 0$ define the function
$$f_{X|Y=y}(x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}. \hspace{1cm} (*)$$

So for each fixed value of $y$, $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ is a function of $x$.  Now let $X|Y=y$ denote the random variable with the above pdf and let $g$ denote some arbitrary function. My question (which may seem rather trivial) concerns notation:

$$ \text{Are the random variables  }\; g(X|Y=y) \;\text{ and }\; g(X)|Y=y \; \text{equivalent?} $$

(Here, $g(X)|Y=y$ is defined in an analogous way to $(*)$: Let $Z = g(X)$. Then $(g(X)|Y=y) = (Z|Y=y)$ is the random variable with pdf $\frac{f_{Z,Y}(z,y)}{f_Y(y)},$ where $f_{Z,Y}(z,y)$ denotes the joint distribution of $Z$ and $Y$.) Assuming the random variables are equivalent, is it because the two notations are equivalent? Or can we prove that these two random variables are equivalent? (Perhaps I am overthinking this...)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have vector $(X,Y)$ with joint pdf (so that marginals has pdf too, due to Fubini). Then you can find conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$, that is $\mathbb P(X \in \cdot | Y)$. Let $\mu(\cdot | Y)$ denote the conditional distribution $X|Y$ (that is $\mu(A|Y) = \mathbb P(X \in A | Y)$, one can actually show that it is absolutelly continuous so your density $f_{X|Y}$ exists). Now, take any $g$ which which is an diffeomorphism (so that for absolutelly continuous random variable $Z$, $g \circ Z$ is still absolutelly continuous). Denote $Z_y$ the random variable with $\mu(\cdot | y)$ distribution. You ask, whether $g \circ Z_y$ has the distribution $\nu(\cdot | y)$ where $\nu(A|Y) = \mathbb P(g(X) \in A | Y)$.

We have $\mathbb P( g(Z_y) \in A) = \mathbb P(Z_y \in g^{-1}(A)) = \mu(g^{-1}(A) | y)$.

Moreover $\nu(A|Y) = \mathbb P(g(X) \in A|Y) = \mathbb P(X \in g^{-1}(A) | Y) = \mu(g^{-1}(A)|Y)$, so $\nu(A|y) = \mu(g^{-1}(A)|y)$

That is, $g(Z_y)$ has $\nu(\cdot | y)$ distribution, which by definition is the distrubution of $g(X)$ given $Y=y$

Comment: In fact, I didn't used the assumption about existence of pdf. The distributions of those variables are equal, so iff one of them has density, then the other must have, too and the densities have to be equal (in case $(X,Y)$ has joint pdf and $g$ is such that $(g(X),Y)$ has joint density, then for example you can be sure that densities exist)

Comment: Thank you! This was essentially the answer I was looking for. Though it seems I potentially erred in calling g(X)|Y=y and g(X|Y=y) "random variables," though I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "conditional random variable" in probability theory. You can say "conditional PDF of $g(X)$ given $Y=y$", but not "conditional random variable $g(X|Y=y)$". Both $g(X|Y=y)$ and $g(X)|Y=y$ are **not** random variables, and if written as is, without context, are an abuse of notation.

Comment: I agree, I assumed in my answer that @Leonidas question was about the distribution of $g(X)$ given $Y=y$ and distribution of $g(Z)$ where $Z$ has the same distribution as $X$ given $Y=y$.

Comment: @kludg Thank you for your answer--could you elaborate on why g(X|Y=y) and g(X)|Y=y are not random variables (based on how I defined them in my question)? I'm not seeing where the problem is...

Comment: @Leonidas there is little to elaborate; as are, the notations $g(X|Y=y)$ ans $g(X)|Y=y$ are nonsense. You need some context to make sense, ex $\operatorname{E}[g(X)|Y=y]$

Comment: @kludg So in other words, g(X|Y=y) and g(X)|Y=y only make sense as arguments of an integral operator? (e.g. E[X], Var[X], etc...) Is the fact that these notations don't make sense because the usual definition of conditional probability, P(A|B) := P(A,B)/P(B), fails since P(B) = P(Y=y) = 0 in this case?